# How to turbulence the position of the point clouds in the geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I wanted to make an animation of the appearance from chaos, but my knowledge is not enough.

My geonodes:

[image]

Еxpected result:

[image]

Until I found the answer and do it through the Erindale Toolkit,the result is not the one you need, but at least something..
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please describe your goal in more detail? ...it's not at all clear to me what you actually want to achieve, or what that should ultimately look like.